# how i can put menu at left of panel in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, bootstrap-modal

Im triying to put a menu left to shopping cart , i use this code

{{> menu2}}

but not works

```html
{{> menu2}}

<div class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-horizontal" class="row">
 <form action="/search2" id="search_form" method="post">
  <div class="col-md-55 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 search-bar">
            <div class="col-md-02">
                <div class="search-bar-input input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="frm_search" id="frm_search" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search the shop">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="btn_search" type="submit">Search</button>
                        <a href="/" class="hidden-xs btn btn-warning btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
















 
</div>
<div class="row"> 
 <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        {{#if filtered}}
            <div class="product-layout left-pad-30 col-md-12">
                <strong>Showing results for: {{search_term}}</strong>
            </div>
        {{/if}}
        <div class="product-layout col-md-12">
            {{#ifCond results.length '==' 0}}
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p class="text-danger">kamehameha</p>
                </div>
            {{/ifCond}}
            {{#each results}}
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        {{#if product_permalink}}
                            <div class="product_wrapper">
                                <a href="/product/{{this.product_permalink}}">
                                    <div class="vertical-center thumbnail-image-container">
                                        {{#if product_image}}
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{this.product_image}}" alt="...">
                                        {{else}}
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="/uploads/placeholder.png" alt="...">
                                        {{/if}}
                                    </div>
                                    <h3 class="product-title product-title-home top-pad-10">
                                        {{this.product_title}}
                                    </h3>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        {{else}}                     
                            <a href="/product/{{this._id}}">
                                <div class="vertical-center thumbnail-image-container">
                                    {{#if product_image}}
                                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{this.product_image}}" alt="...">
                                    {{else}}
                                        <img class="img-responsive" src="/uploads/placeholder.png" alt="...">
                                    {{/if}}
                                </div>
                                <h3 class="product-title product-title-home top-pad-10">
                                    {{this.product_title}}
                                </h3>
                            </a>
                        {{/if}}
                        <h3 class="product-price text-center">
                            {{format_amount product_price}}
                        </h3>
                        <p class="text-center">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary add-to-cart" data-id="{{this._id}}" role="button">Add to cart</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
 </div>










</form>

</div>

{{#if editor}}
    <script src="/javascripts/markdown-it.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/markdown-editor.js"></script>
{{/if}}



[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

My panel is high up the shopping cart

please help me

please help me

[image]

Comment: Please fix your snippet so we could see the actual result.

Comment: sorry but i dont know this well i have to upload bootstrap librarys

Comment: No you don't . You can use a CDN link. Take it from here: https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my problem i put 
{{> menu2}} after

```
    <div class="product-layout col-md-12">
      {{> menu2}}
        {{#ifCond results.length '==' 0}}
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="text-danger">kamehameha</p>
            </div>

        {{/ifCond}}
        {{#each results}}
```

[image]

the checkbox without text isnt a error   ,  I still have to add the text